# What does this Kotlin return value mean? : (Product) -> Boolean

Tags: kotlin, lambda

I struggle to understand what kind of return value this is:

```
private fun someFun(products: List<Product>): (Product) -> Boolean {
// something
}
```

What's this kind of return value called and what does it do?

Answer (score 5):

### Overview

`(Product) -> Boolean` is called a **function type**. See the [official doc](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types) for more.

The key topic here is **lambda** or **high-order functions**. Essentially, you can think of `someFun` as a method that returns *another method* - or rather something that can turn `Product`s into `Boolean`s.

### Usage

This is how your code could be completed and used:

```
private fun someFun(products: List<Product>): (Product) -> Boolean {
  // 'it' is Product, now you have to return a Boolean
  return { it.isExpensive }
}

// and usage:
val result = someFun(products)

val foo: Boolean = result(someProduct)
val bar: Boolean = result(anotherProduct)
```

So you can use it like a function, invoking it on `Product`s, getting `Boolean` in return.

### Example

Might be easier to understand with another, more concrete example:

```
val wordCounter: (String) -> Int = { it.split(" ").size }

println(wordCounter("hello")) // 1
println(wordCounter("hello world")) // 2
```

`wordCounter` is an object of type `(String) -> Int`. It can be used to *turn* `String`s into `Int`. Whenever you use it, it executes the code you wrote earlier (the lambda). So it essentially is like as if you would have created a function, just that its an object instead - a *function object*.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! The wordCounter example was very helpful. But I still struggle with the code under Usage and with understanding what the purpose of someFun() is. What’s the purpose of using products: List<Product> in the parameter since nothing is really happening with that list? If the goal is to get val foo: Boolean = result(someProduct) , isn’t it easier to just write a simple method like so: private fun isItExpensive(product: Product): Boolean { return product.isExpensive}

Comment: Well, I would expect that the concrete implementation of the method (which you left out) is actually using the list. For example, maybe it checks if the given product is in the list of products or similar. `return it in products`. Otherwise it indeed would be kinda obsolete.

Answer (score 3):

This is a [function type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#function-types). `someFun` returns a function that accepts a `Product` and returns a `Boolean`.

E.g.

```
fun foo(product: Product): Boolean {
    ...
}
```